# Adding items to a listbox the ajax way

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm following an example on how to call a c# function from javascript. I got a textbox that should autocomplete the users input. This works when i make the target control the textbox, meaning that while the user is typing the textbox will autocomplete the request.

However, i want a listbox to hold the matching cases.

This is the javascript code:

```
function CallMe(src, dest) {
var ctrl = document.getElementById(src);
// call server side method
PageMethods.GetNews(ctrl.value, CallSuccess, CallFailed, dest);
}

function CallSuccess(res, destCtrl) {
var dest = document.getElementById(destCtrl);
dest.value = res;
}

function CallFailed(res, destCtrl) {
alert(res.get_message());
}
```

Down below is the c# code, it takes a string input and returns the entries that match the input.
I've tested this by using a foreach loop that goes through the list and adds the items to the listbox, i need to do this the ajax way/style.

However i would like it to be updated constantly by using javascript.

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetNews(string input)
{
    List<string> listan = new List<string>();
    SqlDataReader reader;
    string tempstr = "";
    if (input == null || input.Length == 0)
        return null;
    SqlConnection conn = null;
    try
    {
        string connection = "example";
        conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
        string sql2 = "Select News from Nyheter where News LIKE '%'+@News+'%'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql2, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("News", input);
        conn.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            tempstr = (string)reader["News"];
            listan.Add(tempstr);
        }

        return listan;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

This is the load code, the first example works, Textie is a textbox that auto completes when a match is found. The problem is that i want the matches to get added to a listbox instead. The second example doesn't work and i cant figure out why, the items doesnt get added to the listbox.

```
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {     

        Textie.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:CallMe('" + Textie.ClientID + "',        '" + Textie.ClientID + "')");

        //ListBox1.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:CallMe('" + Textie.ClientID + "', '" + ListBox1.ClientID + "')");

    }
```

Hints would be appreciated and is there a easier way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Textie.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:CallMe('" + Textie.ClientID + "',        '" + Textie.ClientID + "')");
```

Put this code in page load but not in "NOt postback" code.